# How to specify computed property dependency in EmberJS on an array of objects that contain another array

Tags: coffeescript, ember.js

I am using EmberJS and I am trying to setup the dependency on a computed property. A visitor can contain multiple tickets (an array), and I have access to an object containing an array of visitors. This is my computed property. How can the property be recomputed when a ticket is added to any of the visitors in the visitors array?

```
App.AttendanceController = App.SlideBaseController.extend
eligibleVisitors:
    (->
        return @getElegibleVisitors()
    ).property('App.state.session.visitors.@each.type')

allEligibleVisitorsAttending:
    (->
        return _.all @getElegibleVisitors(), (visitor)->
            return visitor.tickets.length > 0 and _.any visitor.tickets, (ticket)->
                return ticket.EventID is content.Event.ID
    ).property('App.state.session.visitors.tickets')

getElegibleVisitors:->
    return _.filter App.state.session.visitors, (visitor)->
        return visitor.type isnt App.VisitorTypes['Infant']
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

`.property('App.state.session.visitors.@each.tickets.@each')`

Updates when any ticket is added to any visitor.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please add a comment explaining why you think this is not a good answer

Comment: @Teddy Zeenny, I tried your suggestion but that didn't work, though that makes sense to me. For debugging purposes I add a breakpoint inside the property from within the Chrome dev tools -> source tab, but the code never gets hit after I add a ticket to a visitor.

Comment: looks like it's a bug in Ember.js https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/541 as @Sherwin Yu says.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible right now and won't be for Ember 1.0. See here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/541

Nested `@each` properties don't trigger observers correctly.

I faced a similar problem (nested tree structure) -- I got around it by having each child node have a  reference property to the parent node, and then adding

```
Node = Ember.Object.extend
  nodeParent: null # to point at parent
  nodeChanged: (->
      @get('nodeParent')?.notifyPropertyChange 'notifier'
  ).observes 'various', 'properties
```

I used 'notifier' as a general key that other properties on the parent can bind to; when things in the child change, it causes a property change on the `parent.notifier`, which will in turn trigger other properties you want.

This is a hacky work around. Plus side is that it works, downside is you have to keep track of the child-parent relationship; i.e., for you, each `Ticket` needs to a reference to its `Visitor`